# Appending to a file in Ruby instead of replacing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

The following ruby code is replacing the entire contents of the file. **How can I just append to the end of the file and keep it's existing contents intact?**

```
File.open("db/seeds.rb", "w") do |f|
    f.write "Blog::Engine.load_seed"
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use append mode (`"a"`):

```
File.open("db/seeds.rb", "a") do |f|
```

[Here is a link to the docs, on the different modes you can specify when opening a file.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode)

Answer (score 1):

Write in append mode 'a'

```
File.write('db/seeds.rb', "Blog::Engine.load_seed", nil , mode: 'a')
```